# Is there a slang word or phrase for someone who is always playing dirty tricks or unpleasant practical jokes on his friends and acquaintances?

Tags: phrases, expressions, slang, epithet-requests

context:

- He will surreptitiously introduce a frog into your handbag.
- You leave your car keys on a desk, he sees it and hides it somewhere.
- He may offer you M&M type candies that will leave your mouth entirely blue.

> Although most of us would call this person "a jerk", "an asshole", "a creep", or "an s.o.b.",  all these terms are generic and not specific for "one who plays dirty and unpleasant tricks".

I'm ***not looking for lists***. One word or phrase will be enough provided there is a reference link.

Comment: I would say that "prankster" is the best single word for this, although it doesn't convey a strong sense of the tricks being unpleasant/cruel.

Comment: I assume that you are looking for something that would convey the fact that said jokes are in rather bad taste?

Comment: @thkala sure, that's it.

Comment: "The defendent"?

Comment: 'Malicious prankster'?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following, although not slang, may be relevant:

• *[practical joker](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/practical_joker)*, “someone who instigates practical jokes”  –  wiktionary
• *[prankster](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prankster#Noun)*, “One who performs pranks” –  wiktionary
• *[trickster](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trickster#Noun)*, “One who performs a trick”; also “A mythological figure responsible for teaching others through the use of guile and treason”  –  wiktionary

Wikipedia's *[practical joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practical_joke)* article says the following:

> A practical joke (also known as a prank, gag, jape or shenanigan) is a mischievous trick or joke played on someone, generally causing the victim to experience embarrassment, perplexity, confusion, or discomfort. Practical jokes range from confidence tricks [to] hoaxes ... Practical jokes or pranks are generally lighthearted, reversible and non-permanent, and aim to make the victim feel foolish or victimised to a degree, **but may also involve cruelty verging on bullying if performed without appropriate finesse.**  [emph. added]

Comment: "Jokester" is another term.

Comment: Also, *jester*.

Comment: Also *[japester](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/japester)*

Answer (score 9):

The slang term *troll* seems to be acquiring this meaning.

*Troll* has been used for a number of years to refer to a person who makes inflammatory posts in Internet forums for the purpose of annoying others or stirring up trouble.  More recently, it seems to also refer to people who perpetrate real-life pranks for similar purposes.  *Troll* seems to have a stronger connotation of mean-spiritedness than *prankster* or *trickster*.

I'm having trouble finding an authoritative citation (can anyone help?), but for example there is a website named "Art of Trolling" which collects examples of both real-life and Internet pranks.

Comment: But "troll" is not well-known (in that sense) outside of the techie & social media communities.

Comment: (Interestingly, I'm pretty sure "troll", in this sense, is derived from the fishing activity of "trolling", which involves dragging a baited hook or lure through the water to see what bites at it.  Different from the troll hiding under the bridge.)

Comment: @HotLicks: The "social media community" is rapidly approaching a majority of the population in many places, and in certain demographics (e.g. teenagers in industrialized nations) probably represents nearly everybody.  (I'm not saying they all know this word, of course.)

Comment: @HotLicks I always assumed the term came from a combination of the two, though I have no proof. A troll, *when I first heard it used*, seemed to indicate someone who just spent their time in their basement with nothing better to do than annoy people online and, hopefully, *(in a "trolling" manner)* their broad or targeted remarks would make one or a few people take them seriously and get angry at them. Now, when "troll" is used, it seems to mean someone who tries to make people angry or distressed for his/her own satisfaction.

Comment: Originally it applied to comments and posts that attempted to stir up a fight -- goes back 20-30 years.  The similarity to dragging bait through the water is obvious.  The "troll" was the comment/post, not the person doing the posting.  The fact that "troll" also happened to be a mischievous elf didn't hurt things, but I'm pretty sure it was not the original allusion.

Comment: @HotLicks Posters who would tell other posters "Don't reply to the troll" is consistent with this idea. Such a comment could be misconstrued as replying to the person who made the post, rather than the post itself. As people continue to misunderstand use of the word "troll", it changes from the post itself to the person making the post, the one "trolling".

Comment: Urban Dictionary has [definitions for troll](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=troll) dating back to 2002. Not exactly authoritative but **1)** OP was asking for slang, and that's UD's primary function and **2)** in internet years, 2002 is *dead*. (Oh, but I'm not upvoting because I'm opposed to language drift. Trolling is more subtle than random pranks, something that artoftrolling.com gets wrong all the time. Prankster, Jokester etc. are much better terms for what the OP asks.)

Comment: @PatrickM: *Troll* in the sense of an Internet troublemaker is certainly at least that old.  The sense of a real-life prankster is newer, and most of the UD definitions don't include that sense (though some do).

Comment: @Dispensador - Yeah, it quickly evolved to "don't feed the troll", locking in the view of the person as the troll, rather than the post.  But I'm pretty certain that it started in the fishing sense.

Comment: 'Troll' is from 'trawling for newbies'. http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/T/troll.html via 'troll fishing'. Certainly in recent years it has acquired the 'troll under the bridge' connotation.

Comment: A troll in the modern social media "dont feed the troll" sense doesn't play tricks on his acquaintences (as requested by the OP), he plays tricks on people he doesn't know, pseudo-anonymously.

Answer (score 5):

You could figuratively call that person an [imp](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imp).  I would quote Wikipedia, which mentions [imp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imp)s' affinity for pranks, but the entry is not sourced well.

Comment: There are a number of different names (in different languages and cultures) for elf-like creatures who are anywhere from benignly mischievous to out-and-out evil -- imp, troll, nisse, tomte, et al.  Probably none carry the desired connotation in ordinary US/Brittish English, however.

Comment: I can't imagine someone answering "a person who plays unpleasant jokes all the time" to the question "what is an imp".

Comment: @GreenAsJade I don't think you're taking context into account.  If someone were to ask me what it specifically means if you call a person an imp, I would answer with something along the lines of how the person must be a source of unpleasant mischief.

Comment: I see - I think that's fair.

Answer (score 5):

[rascal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rascal) (Merriam-Webster):

> a person and especially a young person who causes trouble or does things that annoy people

Comment: Some near-synonyms like *rapscallion, varlet, knave, scalawag* are probably just as good as *rascal*.  Also *creep*

Comment: A person who plays tricks all the time probably is a rascal, but rascal does not mean "someone who specifically plays unpleasant jokes all the time".   This answer is like the list that the OP said he's not interested in (jerk etc).

Answer (score 2):

From the OP's detailed description, I'm inclined to believe that these jokes contain an element of maliciousness, the type of practical jokes where the victim may not spontaneously burst out laughing. The OP suggests that we call the person who performs these jokes; a jerk, a s.o.b,  a creep etc. Therefore I suggest the following term

> [**shenanigan**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shenanigan)
>
> 2. a. A playful or mischievous act; a prank.
>      b. Mischief; prankishness. Often used in the plural.
>      ***reckless or malicious behavior that causes discomfort or annoyance in others***

- A person who performs shenanigans.

Apparently, the term *shenanigans* in the US is considered slang,
 and the phrase ***“call shenanigans”*** is used in some regions of the US.

> Shenanigans are activities which are intended to be mischievous and
>   playful. Pranks and jokes, for example, are both considered to be
>   shenanigans. **This term is also sometimes used to refer to deceptive
>   activities which cause harm, irritation, or upset**, and people might
>   use the term “*no shenanigans*” in the sense of “no funny business,”
>   meaning that such activities will not be tolerated. This term is
>   especially common in the United States, which may be its country of
>   origin, although no one is certain. [...]
>   The meaning of the word is also quite slippery, as
>   it is used in a number of different ways, and its adoption as *a slang
>   term* has further clouded its meaning. Curiously, people rarely use a
>   singular form of “shenanigans.” Apparently a single shenanigan is
>   simply unheard of.  Shenanigans can have more **sinister implications**, however. Some people use the term to describe confidence tricks and other deceptive activities which are linked more with wrongdoing than fun times. The victims of these sorts of shenanigans may be embarrassed, humiliated, or injured, and they run the risk of losing money as well.

....

> In some regions of the United States, people use the term ***“call
>   shenanigans”*** to talk about calling someone out for questionable
>   activity. Someone who suspected that he or she was being bilked at an
>   auto repair shop, for example, might say “I call shenanigans,”
>   suggesting that some sort of deceptive activity or wrongdoing might be
>   occurring. Practical jokers may also find the tables turned on them by
>   victims who call shenanigans, putting an end to the joke by indicating
>   that they have seen through it.

Source: [Wise Geek](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-are-shenanigans.htm)

Comment: That's very near what I'm looking for: a word for a person who performs shenanigans.  From the answers I've got so far I suspect there isn't such word.

Answer (score 2):

Mischief Makers - from host of "Hobo Kelly" 1960s kids show on 13 KCOP.

--
https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment mentions  "**You Scallywag**" as a non-helpful comment content.

Answer (score 1):

In Geordie, the word **shan** is a reasonable fit.

(Geordie) unfair, harsh

*Here man! that's pure shan that like*

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shan

Answer (score 0):

The (non-slang) word **boor** literally means an *unrefined, ill-mannered person* (Google), but to me, at least, it has strong connotations of *someone who has an offensive, unfunny sense of humor*.

EDIT:  Although *boor* on its own has been judged unfit, perhaps the phrase *boorish prankster* might best convey the complete meaning you're seeking.

Comment: boor - a rude or insensitive person.   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boor  Sorry, but not what I'm looking for.

Comment: see my edit, above

Answer (score 0):

I would call this person ***mischievous***. It also has the negative sense that you want to convey. [Though, the word has a broader usage also.]

> If you’re the one making prank phone calls at 3 am and you can’t resist short-sheeting your camp counselor’s bunk, you're mischievous. If your dog likes to decorate your house with streamers of toilet paper, he's mischievous, too.
>
> **You can be mischievous in harmless, playful ways, or you might also use the word mischievous to describe behavior that's more than just a little naughty.** If you post online some embarrassing photos of an acquaintance, your more generous friends might describe your behavior as mischievous, although others might accuse you of being downright mean. Keep in mind that the word has only three syllables: MIS-chuh-vuhs.
>
> <sub>http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/mischievous</sub>

Comment: There is the verb "bullyrag" also with the negative sense you want: (tr) to bully, esp by means of cruel practical jokes. [thefreedictionary]. But the noun usage "bullragger" is not common.

Answer (score 0):

'Kidder" comes to mind now which can indicate childish behavior including practical jokes by anyone regardless of age. Its ok to have some humor but some go to the excess at the discomfort of others.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for American slang: **busted ass prankster**  http://ohhla.com/anonymous/getoboys/rm_bside/action.gtb.txt

AKA: Playing around or joking with people you should not and its not funny.

More formal: scoun·drel

/ˈskoundrəl/

noun

noun: scoundrel; plural noun: scoundrels

a dishonest or unscrupulous person; a rogue.
https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=scound&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4LENN_enUS557US445&q=scoundrel&gs_l=hp..0.0l5.0.0.2.272875...........0.aTa-KLL8ODw

Comment: Your IPA is wrong.

Comment: Only a link is not an acceptable response. Also, you would probably want to look at the first sentence hanging incomplete!

Comment: Your link didn't take me to "busted ass prankster".  I could find neither the phrase nor the definition there.

Comment: Very poor quality in terms of slang. Its really dirty street talk as spoken by gutter snipes(My Fair Lady). Should have no place in the vocabulary of intelligent people.

Answer (score -1):

How about fiend?

noun

1.
an evil spirit or demon.

synonyms:   demon, devil, evil spirit, imp, bogie;

(Google the word)

Answer (score -2):

I'd call that jerk a regular *Till [Eulenspiegel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Till_Eulenspiegel)*, "an impudent trickster figure originating in Middle Low German folklore." His name is relatively easy to pronounce; it's *oil´ en shpee gull*.

Richard Strauss, the German composer and conductor whose career spanned the last half of the 19th century and the first half of the 20th century, has a famous tone poem entitled "Till Eulenspiegel's Merry Pranks." I commend it to your listening pleasure.

From [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Till_Eulenspiegel):

> "In the stories, he is presented as a trickster who plays practical jokes on his contemporaries, exposing vices at every turn, greed and folly, hypocrisy and foolishness. As Peter Carels notes, 'The fulcrum of his wit in a large number of the tales is his literal interpretation of figurative language.'[4] In these stories, anything that can go wrong in communication does go wrong due to the disparity in consciousness. And it is not the exception that communication gives rise to complications; rather, it is the rule. As a model of communication, Till Eulenspiegel is the inherent, unpredictable factor of complication that can throw any communication, whether with oneself or others, into disarray. These irritations, amounting to conflicts, have the potential of effecting mental paradigm changes and increases in the level of consciousness. Although craftsmen are featured as the principal victims of his pranks, neither the nobility nor the pope is exempt from being affected by him."

Comment: I've searched "Eulenspiegel" and it seems to me that it is more German folklore than an English word.

Comment: @Centaurus: No argument there. The OP didn't specify the language, but if I had thought 1.2 minutes longer I would have realized this site is devoted to ENGLISH language and usage. D'oh! In my defense, though, there are lots of words we English speakers have borrowed from other languages and use in the original language. Some examples come to mind: dummkopf, adios, merci, je ne sais quoi, gracias, amigo, joie de vivre, papier mâché, crescendo, espresso, café, al fresco, yarmulke, czar, epicurean, machete, gringo, junta, macho, machismo, matador, aficionado, politico, incognito. Don

Comment: Your word doesn't sound common at all to the colloquial  English tongue.

Answer (score -2):

The term ***punk*** is more synonymous with a *hooligan* than a *practical joker*, but I would find the term appropriate since the target is being ***punk'd***.

> :  a usually petty gangster, hoodlum, or ruffian
>   <sub>(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/punk))</sub>

For example:

> Villain: Hah, you've been punk'd!
>   Victim: Very funny, punk.

Or:

> Wife: Who would smash our mailbox?
>   Husband: Just some punks, don't worry about it.

<sub>@ChrisSunami points out that alternative definitions of *punk* allow it to be used to refer to the *punk'd* target.</sub>

If you want a term that has more of a negative bite, you may want to use the term ***buffoon***:

> : a stupid or foolish person who tries to be funny
>   <sub>(Source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/buffoon))</sub>

This term may be appropriate if you do not actually feel the pranks are funny.

Comment: *Punk* is a word with several common definitions in American slang, none of which matches this usage.  The "punk" in *Punk'd* is actually the victim, not the prankster --the usage has roots in African American slang where it started as anti-homosexual slur.

Comment: Check definition 3c, that's the origin of *punked*, not 3b.  Also see this, although it's arguably NSFW: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080809124915AASP5nT

Comment: @ChrisSunami: I have already conceded the alternate definitions allow it to be used as you say. I am only saying that I have never heard it used that way.

Comment: I'm sorry to be pedantic about a slang word, but while *punk* can certainly mean *ruffian* or *hooligan*, your extension of it to *prankster* via the term *punked* is simply wrong.  Just because it's slang doesn't mean it doesn't have an actual etymology.

Comment: @ChrisSunami: I believe you are reading more into the answer than intended. I am suggesting a term for someone that behaves immaturely and happens to be proximate to a word describing the immature act.